# Network error when viewing individual activities

Tags: activities

I can view a profile, view all the activities, but when clicking 'view' to view the details for the individual activity I get 'Network error, unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again'. Any thoughts? I've restarted the machine, logged in/out etc, I have privileges to access the information, made sure it's a secure connection, everything I can think of. Any help would be great!

Comment: Can try opening the link on a new tab i.e right click on the link and then 'Open link in new tab'. Can you also check CiviCRM logs and/or php log if you can see any suspicious entires being logged for your activity.

Comment: I'm getting the same error - and yes the activities do come up when I right click the activities tab.

Comment: Could you update your question with relative uris? It's not clear if you mean a contact's summary's activity tab, a custom profile for activities or the activities search results list.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.. here's a video that shows the error. It happens when I select "Activities" tab on the Contact Summary. https://youtu.be/Glhcp7TnJNk

Comment: Reference chat.civicrm.org conversation which points to an extension bug as the cause: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/g8usndh4hj8ybg8b51fp6p4tpa Also this issue in the extension bug tracker https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.activityical/issues/22 V3rmie, if you want some SE karma, you could point to that bug in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Symptoms like you describe match the symptoms of a [bug in the Activity iCalendar Feed extension](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.activityical/issues/22), which has been fixed as of extension version 1.5.

If you've got this extension installed, I recommend a) disabling it temporarily to see if this bug could be at fault, and b) upgrading it to the latest version. (Hat tip to V3rmie for creating the ticket for that bug.)